# go-cmp undefined module errors while building aosp android t dp2 for maple (xperia xz premium)

Tags: go, android-source, sony-xperia, custom-rom, android-tiramisu

i'm having go-cmp undefined module error while trying to build aosp android t dp2, is there any clues on how to resolve this problem?

> error: external/golang-protobuf/Android.gen.bp:1252:1: "golang-protobuf-reflect-protorange" depends on undefined module "go-cmp"                                                                                  error: external/golang-protobuf/Android.gen.bp:1252:1: "golang-protobuf-reflect-protorange" depends on undefined module "go-cmp-cmpopts"                                                                                                                                                                                   #### failed to build some targets (2 seconds) ####

Answer (score 1):

Just download: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/go-cmp/+/refs/heads/master and put it on external folder, but i recommend you wait for the official release since this error is caused by missing stuff and it's not the only error that you might find.